# How to create a calculated column in PowerBi to achieve the below?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the data in the following format.

```
CompanyID    Company Name
1            Nike
2            Adidas
3            Puma
```

I need to create a column and use it in X axis of a line chart or any visual for that matter in such a way that if a user from Nike logs in, in the visual he should "Nike" instead of companyID. But, for others he should the CompanyID.

Comment: How do you know, that the user is from Nike, or any other company?

Comment: There is a column which has the company name for each user

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new conditional column in Power Query or a computed column in DAX and use it instead of `Company Name`.

With Power Query:

[image]

With DAX:

```
Custom Company Name DAX = IF(Companies[CompanyID] = 1, Companies[Company Name], CONVERT(Companies[CompanyID], STRING))
```

Report data:

[image]

Report visuals:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Appreciate it. How can I make it dynamic? It has to change based on the person's company

Comment: To make it dynamic, it must be a measure. However, you can't put a measure in the axis. What is the data source of your report (SQL Server, other relation database, Excel or flat file, etc.) and the storage mode of the dataset (imported, DirectQuery, etc.)?